# How to change date format in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to calculate the beta in stock but when I bring in the data it has a time in the date frame how can I drop it?
[image]

Comment: What do you expect `Ford_df.yyyymm` to return?

Comment: *"I'm trying to calculate the beta in stock"* You're trying to what?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transform a `datetime` object to a `date` object, you can get the date with the `.date` on the index, then just reassign it:

```py
Ford_df.index = Ford_df.index.date
```

If instead you want the index to be a string with your custom format (*%Y-%m* in this example) then do:

```py
Ford_df.index = Ford_df.index.strftime("%Y-%m")
```

Both solutions presume your index is a `DatetimeIndex`. If it is not you can transform it with:

```py
Ford_df.index = pd.to_datetime(Ford_df.index)
```